# Center ul list with a h2 title

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to center a `<ul>` list with a `<h2>` title above it but I can't do it.

I want all elements of `.navig` to be below each `<h2>` title.

It seems like it's an issue with the bullet points because I want to remove them.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'BenchNine', sans-serif;
    font-size: 120%;
}

header{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 9px 0px rgba(143,143,143,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 9px 0px rgba(143,143,143,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 9px 0px rgba(143,143,143,1);
}

.navig {
    text-align:left;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 180px;
}

#menu{
   text-align: center; 
  
}
#menu div{
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 10%;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5{
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
}

h1 {
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=BenchNine" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- En-tête -->
    <header>
  
        <h1>Accueil</h1>
        <!-- Menu de navigation -->
            <div id="menu">
                <div>
                    <h2>Recettes salées</h2>
                    <ul class="navig">
                        <li><a href="recettes_salees/omelette.html">Omelette au tofu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="recettes_salees/feuilletes.html">Feuilletés maison</a></li>
                        <li><a href="recettes_salees/aubergines.html">Aubergines au four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Recettes sucrées</h2>
                    <ul class="navig">
                        <li><a href="recettes_sucrees/tarte.html">Tarte fraise / chocolat</a></li>
                        <li><a href="recettes_sucrees/daifuku.html">Daifukus ou mochis</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Lifestyle</h2>
                    <ul class="navig">
                        <li><a href="#">Tutos beauté</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bons plans</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div>
    </header>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dd4s0tqL/

Pic : https://puu.sh/wR3cj/e680f8a7a9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove padding from ul and give text-align property to li, like below

```
.navig {
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.navig li {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n31mnc0j/) for you

**Edit:**

For equal with,you need following changes in current style rules:

```
#menu{
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;

}

#menu div{
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 35%;
}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n31mnc0j/1/)

Comment: Just one more little thing : How can I have each of the 3 h2 titles have the same width ? That is to say about 33% of the width of the page ? By doing this, I will have the title "Recettes sucrées" under the h1 title "Accueil" and that's exactly what I want.